# Lock exposure for 3 consecutives photos

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

Is there a way to lock exposure for 3 consecutives photos with an interval of 10sec so that the light doesn't change during the process? (Timer)

```
do {
     try self.currentCaptureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
         if self.currentCaptureDevice.exposurePointOfInterestSupported {
             self.currentCaptureDevice.exposurePointOfInterest = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
             self.currentCaptureDevice.exposureMode = .Locked
         }
      self.currentCaptureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()            
}
catch let error as NSError {
     print(error)
}
```

I noticed that the exposure is set back to default after the first photo.

Comment: I have also this problem!